# Difference between Java Post Request and browser post request

Tags: java

I am trying to use api of one popular russian social networks. I am using OAuth via Java HttpUrlConnection. The problem is, when I send post data via Java, I get 401 response code. When I copy request and paste it browser, I get redirect to URL containing access token I need. That means that my post request is correct, but why when I send it with Java I get 401 error? When I send request with incorrect password, I get 200. It means that request is correct too.

```
private void getHomeAuth() throws Exception {
        String url = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=APP_ID&scope=friends&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&v=5.34&response_type=token";

        URL oauth = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) oauth.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response code: " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
            response.append(inputLine + "\n");
        reader.close();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("auth.html");
        writer.print(response);
        writer.close();
        parse();
        cookies = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
        referer = connection.getURL().toString();
    }



private void postAuth() throws Exception {
        email = URLEncoder.encode("example@gmail.com", "UTF-8");
        password = "password";
        _origin = URLEncoder.encode(_origin, "UTF-8");
        String url = "https://login.vk.com/?act=login&soft=1";
        URL post = new URL(url);
        String urlParameters = "ip_h=" + ip_h + "&_origin=" + _origin + "&to=" + to + "&expire=" + expire + "&email=" + email + "&pass=" + password;
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) post.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();



        System.out.println("Sent post. Response code: " + responseCode + "\nRequest: " + post.toString() + urlParameters + "\nRequestMethod: " + con.getRequestMethod());

    }
```

I also tryied to send this request via addon in browser, and the result was correct. I obtained access token from redirect link.

Maybe the problem is that something inside request is incorrect. I have tried to monitor requests from java app, but I failed.

Comment: Maybe the site checks for a [Referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) or some kind of [XSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention) token?

Comment: Unfortunately, adding a Referer doesn't solve the problem. In fact, I even tried to make a complete copy of request by using TamperData, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with this kind of problem is that the http request that first authenticates the user also puts cookies (scope varies from case to case) into the response and subsequent http requests are expected to contain those cookies.  Look very closely at the complete returned response headers to see what cookies might have been returned.