# Monitor traffic of Java Application

Tags: java

I have a console Java application. Some of HTTP requests return error codes, and I want to debug them. In browser I can watch POST requests in detail, but how can I manage to do it in Java application?

Comment: You need to provide more details. 1) Do you have the source code for this application? 2) Is the application making or receiving the HTTP requests? 3) Any **relevant** code would be welcome so we have a starting point for answering.

Comment: Ok. Yeah, I am the author. It is a client application for popular social network. I send requests to get access token via OAuth. Code is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783406/difference-between-java-post-request-and-browser-post-request)

Answer (score 2):

In your getHttpRequest (or whatever it is called) method print incoming request.
That would be the simplest solution.

More sophisticated - you can extend standard classes which work with requests and modify methods which get requests to print them first.

Answer (score 1):

Try Wireshark or fiddler.  The both sniff traffic in a similar manner as firefox and various browsers do now.